# How to check if interger is Empty or not in Android

Tags: android

Hello I need help i have value which is an integer i want to check if the myvalue is empty or not empty.

```
Bundle mArgs = getArguments();
int myValue = mArgs.getInt("key");
if(myValue.equal(null)){
    TextView textview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.value);
    textview.setText(""+myValue);
}
```

I am getting an error that equal cannot be resolved.

Comment: Sorry, what programming language is that supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int` can never be `null`, it will be `0` if not initialized.

Do something like this:

`if(myValue==0)`

Comment: i want to check if that int has something inside it or not

Comment: yes, and that's how you should check. Because `int` **can't** be `null`. It will be `0` if not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

When you putInt in bundle, parameter must be initialized.

```
//wrong
int param;
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("key", param);

//right
int param = 0;
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("key", param);

Bundle mArgs = getArguments();
int myValue = mArgs.getInt("key");

if (maValue == 0){
}
```

Comment: I did that but the app stops (unfortunately music stopped).

Comment: `int` doesn't require initialization. By default, it will be `0`.